# Install Different Pages on the Same Domain as Separate MS Edge Apps

Tags: email, calendar, microsoft-edge, outlook.com

MS Edge (Chromium) Apps are "installed" by opening a website with Edge and selecting the menu `Apps/Install this site as an App`. In this way, they appear without the browser's tabs and borders and look and behave like desktop Apps. However, I have found no way to "install" different webpage of the same domain as separate Apps.

In particular, for the domain [https://outlook.com/](https://outlook.live.com/) I have not found a way to install both the email view [https://outlook.com/mail](https://outlook.live.com/mail) and the calendar view [https://outlook.com/calendar](https://outlook.live.com/calendar) as separate MS Edge Apps.

In fact, after installing one of the two websites, the MS Edge `Apps` menu only gives me the option to `Open in Outlook` rather than allowing me to `Install this site as an App`.

It would seem natural to be able to have separate MS Edge Apps for both Mail and Calendar rather than always having to switch between the two views.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue with bbb.co.uk/iplayer and bbc.co.uk/sounds. BBC iPlayer and BBC Sounds are distinct Web Apps. I cannot install BBC Sounds without uninstalling BBC iPlayer.

It used to be possible when Edge just created shortcuts for Web Apps (like Chrome still does), but when Microsoft updated Edge to install/register Web Apps as proper Windows 10 apps it looks like this broke. If you right click on an Edge Web App on your `Start Menu -> More` you'll see each one has an `App Settings` option.

I know this as I used to have both pinned but had an issue with my web apps so uninstalled them all and now can't reinstall BBC Sounds.

Originally, they were just shortcuts that got added to the Start Menu and thus you could copy/manipulate them as you wished:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

I tried dragging the web app from the Start Menu to the Desktop, which created it as a shortcut, but when you `right click -> Properties` it has a unique App ID assigned to it. This points it to the website address.

All I can think is use Chrome for the second web app, which is a poor workaround.

Hopefully, Microsoft will fix this obvious bug. Edge isn't letting you install another web app that's the same domain as a web app you already have installed.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to install different pages of the same domain (in my case, it was two gmail accounts I use) as separate Edge Apps by using separate browser profiles. One minor downside this workaround has is that you can't pin both apps on your Taskbar separately, but other that that it works just great.